# Zombies found on minecraft server with mobs disabled

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm pretty new to Minecraft having only just bought the game about a week ago, so apologies if I'm missing something obvious here (I've attempted to search for the answer, but didn't find any relevant results)

I've got a private minecraft server on my home network in survival mode with `spawn-monsters` disabled and normal difficulty, I've not seen any hostiles, or at least not until just now. I've just found a location in the world, deep underground, where I've found what was a fully enclosed pitch black room that was full of zombies. I got overwhelmed by them within seconds, but I did briefly notice a number of storage chests and other items within the room.

If it is relevant, I found the room by accident when I saw my first [moss cobblestone](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Moss_Stone). Not knowing exactly what the block was, I mined them thinking I'd found another resource, in doing so, this room was revealed.

I'm the only person that has played on the server (it's behind a firewall, and I stop and start the server on demand).

Is there any explanation for this? I didn't expect to see any hostiles at all with `spawn-monsters` option disabled. I'm going to head back as soon as I get chance, but was wondering what it might be?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You found a [Dungeon](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Dungeon). These contain [Monster Spawners](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Monster_Spawner).

The `spawn-monsters` [multiplayer option](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Server.properties#Minecraft_server_properties) in the server's config file only controls *natural*, random monster spawns in dark areas. Unless the server difficulty is also set to Peaceful (or 0), Monster Spawners will still be active if you go near them.

Comment: I think typing /gamerule doMobSpawning false will disable all mob spawns. You must be OP to type this command. This is not in your server.properties file.

Answer (score 13):

What you've found is a [Dungeon.](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Dungeon) Specifically, a Zombie dungeon. It contains a [Monster Spawner](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Monster_Spawner) which is able to spawn monsters even if `spawn-monsters` is disabled. The only way to stop a spawner from spawning monsters, is to fully light up the area, or set the server to peaceful.

Comment: +1; Many thanks. Perfectly good answer, but I can only accept one, which I did based upon response time.

Answer (score -3):

That is called a dungeon.  It contains a mob spawner mossy cobble and chests.  The spawn-monster command can't stop this.

Comment: So what're you adding to last year's answers?

Comment: (I didn't mean to be rude, but there's plenty of [unanswered questions](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/unanswered) you could answer instead of rephrasing existing answers, intentionally or not)